# Multiple count queries with same grouping

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve the count of different values with different WHERE in the queries but have them all grouped by the same value.

I tried with following example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (  SELECT COUNT(id) AS mail FROM leadz WHERE source = 'mail' UNION ALL
                 SELECT COUNT(id) AS phone FROM leadz WHERE source = 'phone' UNION ALL
                 SELECT COUNT(id) AS direct  FROM leadz WHERE source = 'direct' UNION ALL 
                 SELECT COUNT(id) AS external FROM leadz WHERE source = 'external' 
                       ) GROUP BY date";
```

Then I try to access the data by using:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "in date ".$row['date'].": ".$row['mail'].",".$row['phone'].",".$row['direct'].",".$row['external']."<br>";
```

This obviously is not working. Anyone help appreciated.

Comment: Why `GROUP BY date` here?

Comment: I need these counts to be grouped by dates so I have a count of each for each day.

Comment: OK, I think you have to add some sample data and desired result to make us understand this clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something where instead of separate sub-queries you use a CASE statement with a sum thusly:

Original Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (  SELECT COUNT(id) AS mail FROM leadz WHERE source = 'mail' UNION ALL
             SELECT COUNT(id) AS phone FROM leadz WHERE source = 'phone' UNION ALL
             SELECT COUNT(id) AS direct  FROM leadz WHERE source = 'direct' UNION ALL 
             SELECT COUNT(id) AS external FROM leadz WHERE source = 'external' 
                   ) GROUP BY date";
```

Updated using a sum of with conditions:

```
$sql = "SELECT
l.DATE
,SUM(CASE WHEN l.SOURCE = 'mail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SOURCE_MAIL
,SUM(CASE WHEN l.SOURCE = 'phone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SOURCE_PHONE
,SUM(CASE WHEN l.SOURCE = 'direct' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SOURCE_DIRECT
,SUM(CASE WHEN l.SOURCE = 'external' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SOURCE_EXTERNAL
FROM LEADZ AS l
GROUP BY l.DATE";
```

Then to access the output in php you could use something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
extract($r);
echo $DATE.'<BR>'.
'mail: '$SOURCE_MAIL.'<BR>'.
'phone: '$SOURCE_PHONE.'<BR>'.
'direct: '$SOURCE_DIRECT.'<BR>'.
'external: '$SOURCE_EXTERNAL.'<BR><hr>';
}
```

Comment: This would return 1 row per date with counts of the various sources. If the preferred output is rows then @fantaghirocco has the better solution.

Comment: Thats what i need! :)  With this query how would I access the data with php to display a count of mail, phone, direct, and external for each day?

Comment: Did that get you what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT date, source, COUNT(id) AS how_many
FROM leadz 
WHERE source IN ('mail', 'phone', 'direct', 'external')
GROUP BY date, source
ORDER BY date
```

A temporary array can be used to put rows in columns:

```
$tmp = array();

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    $tmp[$row['date']][$row['source']] = $row['how_many'];

foreach ($tmp as $date => $source)
    echo 'in date ' . $date . ': ' . $source['mail'] . ',' . $source['phone'] . ',' . $source['direct'] . ',' . $source['external'] . '<br>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: With this query how would I access the data with php to display a count of mail, phone, direct, and external for each day?

Comment: keep track of the same `date` in the loop then switch on the `source` content

Comment: what you're trying to achieve is to put rows in column: it's not a trivial task in many RDBMS. I think you better keep your SQL as simple as possible an do the trick with the PHP script